# Does a DAO protect real inventors from Patent trolls?

Tags: blockchain, patent

The DAO is a Decentralized Autonomous Organization” (DAO); it can be defined as:-

**a fully automated business entity (FAB), or distributed autonomous corporation/company (DAC) is a decentralized network of narrow-AI autonomous agents..**  [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decentralized_autonomous_organization)

[Vitalik Buterin coined the term](https://blog.ethereum.org/2014/05/06/daos-dacs-das-and-more-an-incomplete-terminology-guide/)  DAOism, these may comprise;-

- Autonomous Agents
- Decentralized Applications
- Decentralized Organizations
- Decentralized Autonomous Organizations

"a DAO contains some kind of internal property that is valuable in some way, and it has the ability to use that property as a mechanism for rewarding certain activities." Buterin

**Scenario A**
an inventor develops an opensource project / idea / software  / process
many people deploy/ enact / build upon said process / idea
patent trolls jump into patent with said idea
meanwhile the DAO chugs along happily..

Alas this is not a hypothesis ..if one looks at the tip of the iceberg patent applications from legacy financial organisations like;-

[Goldman Sachs](http://appft.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO2&Sect2=HITOFF&p=1&u=%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fsearch-bool.html&r=1&f=G&l=50&co1=AND&d=PG01&s1=20150332395&OS=20150332395&RS=20150332395)
[Bank of America](http://appft.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO2&Sect2=HITOFF&p=1&u=%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fsearch-bool.html&r=0&f=S&l=50&TERM1=bank%20of%20america&FIELD1=&co1=AND&TERM2=Cryptocurrency%20&FIELD2=&d=PG01)
[Coinplug](http://www.kipris.or.kr/enghome/main.jsp) (select Patents, enter Coinplug, wait 8000/12000 m/sec)

or indeed [patent trends within fintech space](http://patentvue.com/2016/02/16/banks-outpace-technology-companies-with-fintech-patents/) the idea of patenting Fintech ideas is not simply an opinion it is already a reality.

**In the context of the above is it accurate to say that it  will be impossible to sue / prevent a DAO from operating simply / primarily because it operates in the ether and does not exist in the physical realm**?

Comment: I disagree with the question being closed as 'opinion based' - patents have been granted - if the holders choose to excise their 'legal' rights then that = legal battles. There is extensive precedent for this so it is fact not opinion.

Answer (score 2):

This is a good question though its difficult to provide an answer which isn't moot. There have been discussion of a foundation or consortium being formed in order to address this however I haven't come across anything formal. I know I would be interested in support such a cause.